# Quelle différence entre colorier / coloriser / colorer?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, verbes

Quelle est la différence entre les verbes colorier / coloriser / colorer ?
Ils ont tous une signification extrêmement proche (voire identique).

Quelles différences peuvent être faites et dans quelles circonstances doit-on utiliser un de ces verbes et pas un autre?

Comment: Le soleil me *colore* la peau mais je la *colorie* quand je la tatoue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Colorier** est d'usage courant en classe de maternelle pour les dessins d'enfants réalisés au feutre ou au crayon de couleur.

**Coloriser** s'applique surtout à propos de films tournés originalement en noir et blanc et plus tard rehaussés de couleurs plus ou moins naturelles.

**Colorer** est utilisé pour toute autre mise en couleur, notamment en décoration ou dans la mode.